# MongoDB remove elements depending on element before (Iterating)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to remove ($unset) elements from my MongoDB Objects with condition if the same Object has a similar element.
My Object:

```
{
   "_id": "5eabf8b144345b36b00bfbaa",
   "ranktime": [{
      "pos":"2",
      "datum":"Mon May 05 2020 12:22:52 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)",
      "source":"SOURCE2"
    },{
      "pos":"1",
      "datum":"Fri May 01 2020 12:23:10 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)",
      "source":"SOURCE1"
    },{
      "pos":"37",
      "datum":"Fri May 01 2020 12:25:14 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)",
      "source":"SOURCE2"
    },{
      "pos":"12",
      "datum":"Fri May 01 2020 12:25:14 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)",
      "source":"SOURCE2"
    },{
      "pos":"37",
      "datum":"Fri May 01 2020 18:45:27 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)",
      "source":"SOURCE2"
    }]
}
```

So I want to remove the entry in `ranktime` if `ranktime.source == "SOURCE2"` and if the date is the same as with the object before. Actually I have to iterate through the single elements of `ranktime`. Is this possible in MongoDB ?

The Expected outcome would be:

```
{
   "_id": "5eabf8b144345b36b00bfbaa",
   "ranktime": [{
      "pos":"2",
      "datum":"Mon May 05 2020 12:22:52 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)",
      "source":"SOURCE2"
    },{
      "pos":"1",
      "datum":"Fri May 01 2020 12:23:10 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)",
      "source":"SOURCE1"
    },{
      "pos":"37",
      "datum":"Fri May 01 2020 12:25:14 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)",
      "source":"SOURCE2"
    }]
}
```

Comment: What is your MongoDB version? And why the last one got removed (unique date)

Comment: My Version is 4.2.8 and sorry, I mean only same date (Day), ignoring the time. Thats why last one is removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to process an array and define previous element using [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) and [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) statements. The new [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/index.html) syntax allows you to use aggregation within update statement:

```
db.col.updateMany({}, [
    {
        $set: {
            ranktime: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$ranktime",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: { last: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$value", -1 ] } },
                            in: {
                                $cond: [ 
                                    { 
                                        $and: [ 
                                            { "$eq": [ "$$last.source", "SOURCE2" ] },
                                            { "$eq": [ { $substr: [ "$$last.datum", 0, 15 ] }, { $substr: [ "$$this.datum", 0, 15 ] } ] },
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "$$value",
                                    { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", [ "$$this" ] ] }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Aggregation Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H0qUx5rfkDd)

Comment: thank you very much! This is awesome. 
I just have another problem. Is there away not to only consider the last element, but all elements in the Array? It can happen, that identical objects are not stored one after another. Do you have any advice for this case?
Thank you!

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel you can still use the same approach and refer to `$$value` which contains all the previous values or `$ranktime` to refer to all of them

Comment: Ok, as far as I'm getting it, instead of `$arrayElemAt: [ "$$value", -1 ] ` i have to  I have to  give in the whole array. But setting `vars: { last: "$ranktime }` doesnt work. Is there any documentation about the `$$value ` variable in MongoDB? It's not defined in the `$let` statement but documentation for `$let` says you can only use defined variables, and it also seems not to be a system variable? Thank You!

Comment: `$$value` is the result of the previos iteration of $reduce so it will be an empty array initially, and then it contain a product of `$concatArrays`

Comment: ok, so referring to `$ranktime` (which has all the values) instead of only `$$value` should work then,but i am somehow missing something? https://mongoplayground.net/p/xzOFbfz3Zsa the change is in line 13

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel can you open another question with a good sample data and expected result? I will try to take a look later but need to make sure I understand your case

Comment: Thanks Michal! I posted my question here again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540346/mongodb-remove-elements-depending-on-all-other-elements-iterating