# MongoDB remove elements depending on all other elements (Iterating)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to remove ($reduce) elements from my MongoDB Objects with condition if the same Object has a similar element. My Object:

```
  {
    "_id": "5eabf8b144345b36b00bfbaa",
    "ranktime": [
      {
        "pos": "15",
        "datum": "Mon May 01 2020 12:25:14 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)",
        "source": "SOURCE2"
      },
      {
        "pos": "10",
        "datum": "Fri May 05 2020 12:25:14 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)",
        "source": "SOURCE2"
      },
      {
        "pos": "15",
        "datum": "Mon May 01 2020 18:45:27 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)",
        "source": "SOURCE2"
      },
      {
        "pos": "20",
        "datum": "Fri May 05 2020 18:45:27 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)",
        "source": "SOURCE1"
      },
      {
        "pos": "10",
        "datum": "Fri May 05 2020 12:25:14 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)",
        "source": "SOURCE2"
      },
      {
        "pos": "15",
        "datum": "Mon May 01 2020 18:45:27 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)",
        "source": "SOURCE2"
      }
    ]
  }
```

So I want to remove the entry in ranktime if ranktime.source == "SOURCE2" and if the date is the same as with the object before. Actually I have to iterate through the single elements of ranktime. Is this possible in MongoDB ?

The Expected outcome would be:

```
  {
    "_id": "5eabf8b144345b36b00bfbaa",
    "ranktime": [
      {
        "pos": "15",
        "datum": "Mon May 01 2020 12:25:14 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)",
        "source": "SOURCE2"
      },
      {
        "pos": "10",
        "datum": "Fri May 05 2020 12:25:14 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)",
        "source": "SOURCE2"
      },
      {
        "pos": "20",
        "datum": "Fri May 05 2020 18:45:27 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)",
        "source": "SOURCE1"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB remove elements depending on element before (Iterating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63481659/mongodb-remove-elements-depending-on-element-before-iterating)

Comment: To rephrase your requirements: you want to output `SOURCE2` only if it's date is unique or skip duplicated dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your example you want to output the `ranktime` **unless** it is `SOURCE2` **and** the same date has already been added to the output (but only for `SOURCE2`).

You can use `$reduce` as previously but you need to scan previosly added elements which can be achieved using [$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) operator and since your output contains the third element I'm assuming the repeated date is a stop condition only if the same date has been added for `SORUCE2` so [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) is also needed to prepare the set of previosly added `SOURCE2`s:

```
db.col.updateMany({}, [
    {
        $set: {
            ranktime: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$ranktime",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {
                        $cond: [ 
                            { 
                                $and: [ 
                                    { "$eq": [ "$$this.source", "SOURCE2" ] },
                                    {
                                        $anyElementTrue: {
                                            $map: {
                                                input: { $filter: { input: "$$value", as: "prev", cond: { $eq: { "$$prev.source", "SOURCE2" } } } }, // already added SOURCE2 elements
                                                as: "addedElement",
                                                in: { "$eq": [ { $substr: [ "$$addedElement.datum", 0, 15 ] }, { $substr: [ "$$this.datum", 0, 15 ] } ] }
                                            }                        
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "$$value", // skip current element ($$this) 
                            { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", [ "$$this" ] ] } // add current element to the output
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CielgH0eNhd)

Comment: thats exactly it! thanks so much, master of mongodb queries :)